# HTML / PHP - How to create a Dynamic Table

Tags: php, jquery, html

Good day!

I'd like to create a dynamic table that users will input data and make some calculation.

I'm thinking on doing that in HTML or PHP? Not sure which one???

Can you please give me a clue?

Dynamic table I mean a Table with 3 columns, where 2 columns (value and taxes) will be an input field. and the third column (Taxes) will be calculated from column "Value" using a Formula quoted on the right hand side of each row.

> eg. In the item "Electricity", if the user enters "800" as value, the
>   Taxe for Electricity will be a formula (800 * 0.21) that is "168".
>
> 0.21 is 21 % quoted on the right hand side of the row.

Below is the code snippet of what I tried so far, but I still can't get the same result than in the attached image!

Please can you help !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Salary Calcultor</title>
    </head>
    
    <body>
        
        <p><h3>Salary Calculator [ver 1.0]</h3>=======================</p>
        
        <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Item</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Taxes</td>
            
        </tr>
        
        </table>
        
        <p>Gross Salary</p>
        <p>PAYE (Salaries Tax)</p>
        <p>Pension Fund</p>
        <p>Armed Response</p>
        <p>Maintenance</p>
        <p>Petrol</p>
        
        
        
        
        <form action="workout.php" method="post">
            
            <h4>Gross Salary</h4>
            <input type="text" name="prenom" />
            
            <!-- <input type="submit" value="Valider" /> -->
           
        </form>
        
        <?php
        
        ?>
        
    </body>
    
    
    
</html>
```

Please see below image for description.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML is for static content. It structure the content of a web page using tags, but does not "execute" code.

If dynamic behaviour is required, it can be programmed client-side or server side. For client-side programming in web pages, JavaScript is the typical choice. For server-side programming, there are plenty of options, including php.

For computing a value based on input field, you need to combine HTML (for main page contents, including input fields), and either JavaScript or PHP/any other server-side language for the calculation part.

Comment: Thanks airos. Now I got the Licence to start working. I appreciate that. So How do I make the input cell in value column ? : Should I use php for that?

Comment: I modified the above post to add code that I tried so far but I'm still can't get the same result. Please can you help !!!!